# How to string to primitive type in Mantle?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9.1, github-mantle

I am making application using [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle) with iOS 9.1

```
class SKUser: MTLModel, MTLJSONSerializing {

    var userId:NSNumber = -1
    var firstName:String = ""
    var lastName:String = ""

    var country:String! = ""
    var address:String! = ""
    var company:String! = ""
    var email:String! = ""
    var mobileNumber:NSNumber = -1

    static func JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey() -> [NSObject : AnyObject]! {
        return [
            "userId": "user_id",
            "firstName": "user_first_name",
            "lastName": "user_last_name",
            "country": "user_country",
            "address": "user_address",
            "company": "user_company",
            "email": "user_email",
            "mobileNumber": "user_mobile_number"
        ]
    }
}
```

I am not able to convert **mobile number** and **userId** fields to integer or NSNumber, i have tried a lot but could not find solution

Please help me

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Could you fixed this i need this one too

Answer (score 0):

Try this changes in your code. (Swift 3)

```
class SKUser: MTLModel, MTLJSONSerializing {  
    var userId:NSNumber?
    var firstName:String?
    var lastName:String?

    var country:String?
    var address:String?
    var company:String?
    var email:String?
    var mobileNumber:NSNumber?

   public override static func jsonKeyPathsByPropertyKey() -> [AnyHashable : Any]!  {
        return [
            "userId" as AnyHashable: "userId" as Any,
            "firstName" as AnyHashable: "firstName" as Any,
            "lastName" as AnyHashable: "lastName" as Any,
            "country" as AnyHashable: "country" as Any,
            "address" as AnyHashable: "address" as Any,
            "company" as AnyHashable: "company" as Any,
            "email" as AnyHashable: "email" as Any,
            "mobileNumber" as AnyHashable: "mobileNumber" as Any
        ]
    }
}
```

Notice the lower case "json" in "jsonKeyPathsByPropertyKey" instead "JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey"